# A UIImageView or UIImage Subclass With Other Methods

Tags: iphone

Gentleones,

I would like (at another's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058186/iphone-apps-objective-c-a-graph-and-functions-vs-objects-or-something-like-t)) to extend the functionality of a UIImageView or UIImage so that I can display a particular image in a view and ask it about itself. Since it's a graph, I'd like to be able to ask this particular UIImageView what a particular Y value is returned given a particular X value.

(Ignore creating the graph programmatically. Can't do that for other reasons. Anywho...)

But--now pay attention here!--I'm a n00b! I have successfully written a program that displays the image using addSubView and some other stuff, so I know a little. Enough to be dangerous, anyway.

Can somebody help me out with the best choice (UIImageView or UIImage) and the best way to extend that class so that I can load the image and later query it for relevant info?

Thanks in advance,
Bill

Comment: Should I be using the @interface construct with a UIImage somehow? That's what I sorta' figure out from the Placard example. Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely subclass `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView`, I think that's the best way to follow the MVC pattern..
However, when you say you want the Y value for a particular X value, do you have access to the 'function' that returns the Y for a given X?
If not, you'll have to loop trough all the Y-pixels in an image at a given X-location and determine which pixel is colored and at what Y-location it is. However, the origin of the graph would have to be the bottom-left of the image, it would be inflexible. For more information about that, check out: [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)